# File Upload with Loading progress bar in React (using RTK Query)

Tags: reactjs, redux, file-upload, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Looking to make a component that can take a CSV. (excel) file and upload it to the server.
(with drag and drop functionality, as well as a responsive upload bar showing progress in uploading to the server along with any error handling)

Any advice would be appreciated.  Ideally looking to build this in RTK Query.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

though your question is not descriptive enough, I believe [this topic](https://codevoweb.com/react-rtk-query-react-hook-form-and-material-ui-multipart-formdata/) should help you.
This topic is on uploading images using RTK Query and has the drag-and-drop functionality.